# Camera not showing preview in Samsung Galaxy S7

Tags: java, android, camera, galaxy

I have an app with uses the camera with a SurfaceView.
This is the code for the Surface View:

```
public class CameraView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
private Camera mCamera;

public CameraView(Context context, Camera camera){
    super(context);

    mCamera = camera;
    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    //get the holder and set this class as the callback, so we can get camera data here
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_NORMAL);

  }

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    try{
        //when the surface is created, we can set the camera to draw images in this surfaceholder
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("ERROR", "Camera error on surfaceCreated " + e.getMessage());
    }
  }

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i2, int i3) {
    //before changing the application orientation, you need to stop the preview, rotate and then start it again
    if(mHolder.getSurface() == null)//check if the surface is ready to receive camera data
        return;

    try{
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    } catch (Exception e){
        //this will happen when you are trying the camera if it's not running
    }

    //now, recreate the camera preview
    try{
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("ERROR", "Camera error on surfaceChanged " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (RuntimeException e){

    } catch (Exception e){

    }
  }

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    //our app has only one screen, so we'll destroy the camera in the surface
    //if you are unsing with more screens, please move this code your activity
    //mCamera.stopPreview();
    //mCamera.release();
  }
}
```

And this is the code related to the camera in its Activity:

```
public class CameraOverlay extends ActionBarActivity implements CameraLoopsAdapterDelegate {

private Camera mCamera = null;
private CameraView mCameraView = null;
FrameLayout camera_view;
Bitmap bmp = null;

 private Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Bitmap bmpAux = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
        int rotationInDegrees;//PictureUtil.exifToDegrees(rotation);
        Log.e("", "CAMERA MODE "+cameraMode+" (back, front)="+ CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK+","+CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
        Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        Camera.getCameraInfo(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK, info);
        Log.e("", "CAMERA ORIENTATION "+orientationOnPhoto);
        if(cameraMode == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
            if (orientationOnPhoto == Constants.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_NORMAL)
                rotationInDegrees = 90;
            else if (orientationOnPhoto == Constants.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_INVERTED)
                rotationInDegrees = 270;
            else if (orientationOnPhoto == Constants.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_NORMAL)
                rotationInDegrees = 0;
            else //if (orientationOnPhoto == Constants.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_INVERTED)
                rotationInDegrees = 180;
        }
        else {
            if (orientationOnPhoto == Constants.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_NORMAL)
              rotationInDegrees = 270;
            else if (orientationOnPhoto == Constants.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_INVERTED)
                rotationInDegrees = 90;
            else if (orientationOnPhoto == Constants.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_NORMAL)
                rotationInDegrees = 0;
            else //if (orientationOnPhoto == Constants.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_INVERTED)
                rotationInDegrees = 180;
        }
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        //if (rotationInDegrees != 0f)
            matrix.preRotate(rotationInDegrees);
        bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmpAux, 0, 0, bmpAux.getWidth(), bmpAux.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera_overlay);

    getSupportActionBar().hide();

    camera_view = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.camera_view);
    takePhotoIV = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.camera_takepicture);
    takePhotoIV.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!PermissionsManager.getInstance(CameraOverlay.this).hasGivenPermission("android.permission.CAMERA"))
                return;
            orientationOnPhoto = mOrientation;
            mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
            takePhotoIV.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
    sendTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.send_photo);
    sendTV.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
               // Here we send the photo stored on "bmp" to backend
               resetCamera();
            }
    });

}

public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    if(PermissionsManager.getInstance(CameraOverlay.this).hasGivenPermission("android.permission.CAMERA"))
    {
        try {
            mCamera = Camera.open(cameraMode);//camera mode is an enumerated to use FRONT or BACK camera
            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            parameters.setFlashMode(cameraFlash);
            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("ERROR", "Failed to get camera: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        if(mCamera != null) {
            mCameraView = new CameraView(this, mCamera);//create a SurfaceView to show camera data
            camera_view.addView(mCameraView);//add the SurfaceView to the layout
        }
    }
  }

    public void resetCamera()
{
    if(!PermissionsManager.getInstance(CameraOverlay.this).hasGivenPermission("android.permission.CAMERA"))
        return;
    mCamera.stopPreview();
    mCamera.release();
    camera_view.removeAllViews();
    mCamera = Camera.open(cameraMode);
    try {
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        parameters.setFlashMode(cameraFlash);
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        Log.d("ERROR", "Error setting parameters: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    mCameraView = new CameraView(this, mCamera);//create a SurfaceView to show camera data
    camera_view.addView(mCameraView);//add the SurfaceView to the layout
}

}
```

This code is working ok on all devices I've tested so far:

- When user clicks on Take photo button the photo is taken.
- The frame layout of the camera freezes showing the photo taken.
- When the user clicks on Send photo the photo is sent to backend ok.
- The camera is reset, the frame layout is not freezed and the camera is ready to take a photo again.

Now, some users which have a Samsung Galaxy S7 (android 6) have reported that when they take a photo, it's not showing in the camera view. The frame layout of the camera doesn't freeze, it seems that the camera is still waiting for the user to take a photo.

But if the user clicks on Send, the photo is sent OK to the backend, so the PictureCallback has been called and the Bitmap bmp has been created correctly. But, why the photo has not been shown in its surface?

I've tried to find any documentation about this without success, but there has any problem the Samsung Galaxy S7 with android.hardware.camera? Should I use Camera2 for this device?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with Samsung Galaxy Note S7 Android 6. Have you found any solution so far? Maybe a way to freeze camera manually?

Comment: No sorry, my client finally changes the behavior of that view.